# What's the difference between pm2 and pm2-runtime?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pm2

I've been transferring some projects that have been executing on the same machine to individual dockers each. I've tried to use `pm2` on one of these docker projects to make sure the service would restart if something go wrong (it's a volatile project) and some of the examples demands the Dockerfile to use `pm2-runtime` instead of `pm2`. I've been searching for the differences of these two but I couldn't find something specific, could someone help?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The main difference between pm2 and pm2-runtime is

- pm2-runtime designed for Docker container which keeps an application in the foreground which keep the container running,
- pm2 is designed for normal usage where you send or run the application in the background.

In simple words, the life of the container is the life of `CMD` or `entrypoint`.

For example

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD [ "pm2", "start","/app/server.js"]
```

In this case, the container will die as soon as it run the process.

To deal with this, you have **pm2-runtime**

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=development
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start","/app/bin/www"]
```

[image]

As the container keeps running and it allocates tty session.

From the documentation

> The goal of pm2-runtime is to wrap your applications into a proper
> Node.js production environment. It solves major issues when running
> Node.js applications inside a container like:
>
> - Second Process Fallback for High Application Reliability
> - Process Flow Control
> - Automatic Application Monitoring to keep it always sane and high performing
> - Automatic Source Map Discovery and Resolving Support
>
> Further than that, using PM2 as a layer between the container and the
> application brings PM2 powerful features like application declaration
> file, customizable log system and other great features to manage your
> Node.js application in production environment.

[docker-pm2-nodejs](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/)