# How to access PM2 logs when I run my Node.Js app image using AWS ECS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, pm2

My node.js app runs via AWS ECS. To launch it I use a Docker image through the Task Definition, which contains the following command to start up my app:

```
pm2,ecosystem.config.js
```

The app starts up fine, however, I can't find the PM2 logs.

When I try to access it directly on the EC2 instance where the ECS service is running via

```
/home/ec2-user/.pm2/logs/my-log.log
```

of course there are only the old log files that are there when I launch my app on that instance directly — which makes sense, because if PM2 runs in a Docker container it would also save the log files there.

So is there a way to launch my instance in a way that I could have access to the PM2 log files or that at least I could have them saved on the instance in a specific folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two option to access process logs inside the container.

- Push logs to stdout/stderr of the container and get logs of the container in Cloudwatch ( useful in case of fargate) and also base on 12 factors app.
- Mount Host folder with container logs path

in the first option, you will need a bit changes on your Dockerfile `CMD` so it will push logs to stdout.

```
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "app.js"]
#OR
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "process.yml"]
```

`pm2-runtime` is designed for docker container and its come as a bundle with `pm2`.

[What's the difference between pm2 and pm2-runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962776/whats-the-difference-between-pm2-and-pm2-runtime)

By doing this you will be able to access logs outside of the container also in cloud watch if configured in task definition.

you need to add this in the Task defintion

```
"logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "awslogs-pm2",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "awslogs-nodejs"
                }
            }
```

visit https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/ and look for **awslogs-pm2**

[image]
[using_awslogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

That's standard approach of dealing logs in the container.
[image]

**Mount logs folder**

This the other option is not recommended in production system,

- set log path in pm2 config file, suppose it set to `/app/logs/myapp.log`
- Map host path /home/ec2-user/container-logs with /app/logs/myapp.log

then you will able to find container on host under `/app/logs/myapp.log`
`process.yml`

```
apps:
  - script : myapp.js
    name   : 'api-server'
    error_file : './logs/myapperror.log'
    out_file : './logs/myappoutput.log'
```

Mount config

```
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "database1",
      "image": "my-repo/database",
      "cpu": 100,
      "memory": 100,
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "database_scratch",
          "containerPath": "/var/scratch"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "database2",
      "image": "my-repo/database",
      "cpu": 100,
      "memory": 100,
      "essential": true,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "database_scratch",
          "containerPath": "/var/scratch"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

[ECS bind-mounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html)

Comment: Wow, this is a very good answer. Thank you so much!